# Duplicate operation in transaction?

Tags: horizon, accounts, history

I'm having trouble understanding the operations of this transaction: https://horizon.stellar.org/transactions/f06c6a478b0caac5c8b33512100f70c1aa192bee3af7084f2b693df7f75689bd/operations

It seems the amount `20.0098520` was moved twice with an account merge, once in operation `16530607567802369` and once in `16530607567802370`.

Looking at the affected source account, it seems it was debited and removed twice, with one `account_debited` effect immediately following an `account_removed` effect: 
https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GBSSDVJTXF6XJUN5EWCUXDMCGYGNCIDTPL6G6WM6FTG3G4GDGDKU7Z2T/effects

Lastly, summing up the effects of all `account_created`, `account_debited` and `account_credited` results in a negative balance:

`-20.0098120 = 20.9998920 + 15.0000000 - 15.9900000 - 20.0098520 - 20.0098520`

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, did either of the merges fail? Why are there two merges and how can I build similar transactions?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I rediscovered the infamous Stellar inflation bug: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/software/security-protocol-release-notes.md#v061c-not-widely-released---2017-04-08

> Ledger - security - merge account could be called on an account already merged in the same ledger, causing the Lumens balance of the doubly merged account to be credited multiple times into the destination account
>
> exploited: yes
> rogue transactions caused new Lumens to be created, not accounted for in total coins